# How can you override function redirection in bash?

Tags: bash, function, io-redirection

I recently discovered some `bash` code that used the little-known (well, little known to *me* anyway) feature of function redirection, such as the greatly simplified:

```
function xyzzy () {
    echo hello
} >/dev/null
```

When you call the function with a simple `xyzzy`, it automatically applies the redirections attached to the function regardless of what you've done when calling it.

What I'd like to know is if there's any way to override this behaviour in the call to the function itself, to see the message being generated. I'm reticent to change the file containing all the functions since (1) it's large, (2) it changes regularly, and (3) it's heavily protected by the group that supports it.

I've tried:

```
xyzzy >&1
```

to try to override it but the output still doesn't show up (possibly because `>&1` may be considered a no-op).

---

In other words, given the script:

```
function xyzzy () {
    echo hello
} >/tmp/junk

rm -f /tmp/junk
echo ================
echo Standard output
echo ----------------
xyzzy # something else here
echo ================
echo Function capture
echo ----------------
cat /tmp/junk
echo ================
```

it currently outputs:

```
================
Standard output
----------------
================
Function capture
----------------
hello
================
```

What can I change the `xyzzy` call to, so as to get `hello` printed in the standard output section rather than the function capture section?

And this needs to be *without* trying to read the file `/tmp/junk` after it's created since the *actual* redirections may be to `/dev/null` so they won't *be* in a file.

Comment: Not useful comment: I tried `xyzzy 1>/tmp/aaa` and the file gets touched, but not filled with data. It has the same behaviour as `xyzzy 2>/tmp/aaa`.

Comment: might be worth asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @dogbane, I was torn on that since it seems both programming _and_ Unix. I didn't want to crosspost but, if I can't get an answer here, I suppose I can try it over there later on.

Comment: "If you're wondering if you can override the redirections in the actual call, the answer is no." (from ["More Bash Redirections" on linuxjournal.com](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-bash-redirections)) So, unless you can refactor `xyzzy` into a more-palatable `xyzzy_noredirect`, there is a minimum level of hackery required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of would be to parse the output of `declare -f function_name` and remove the redirection.

This is perhaps the easiest approach. Note that you need to tailor the `awk` script to the specific function layout and it doesn't modify the body of the function at all. That means you can only turn off redirection at the top level. You *could* modify whole call trees of functions to turn off redirection but that would require a `bash` parser capable of recognising and changing function calls within the body.

The following script shows how to do it with your sample function. All the `awk` command does is create a new function `my_xyzzy` which mirrors the `xyzzy` function except for the final line, effectively turning it into:

```
function my_xyzzy () {
    echo hello
}
```

And the complete script as per the specifications:

```
function xyzzy () {
    echo hello
} >/tmp/qqqq

declare -f xyzzy | awk '
    NR==1 {print "my_xyzzy ()"}
    NR==2 {prev=$0}
    NR>2  {print prev;prev=$0}
    END   {print "}"}' >$$.bash
. $$.bash
rm -f $$.bash

rm -f /tmp/qqqq
echo ================
echo Standard output
echo ----------------
my_xyzzy
echo ================
echo Function capture
echo ----------------
cat /tmp/qqqq
echo ================
```

The output of that is:

```
================
Standard output
----------------
hello
================
Function capture
----------------
cat: /tmp/qqqq: No such file or directory
================
```

Comment: I have actually given some though to this in a slightly different way, by passing the actual script file with the functions in it through a filter which changes all function definitions and calls to something like `my_xyzzy` and then sourcing _that._ That's my fallback position if I can't find an easy way to override the redirection, since it'll require a fairly complex parser to catch all edge cases.

Comment: Glenn, I started looking into making my own `bash` variant which would not redirect functions if a variable was set (I can't change the script but running it with a slightly modified `bash` was not discounted) but it became too hard. So I suspect that this is the way I'm going to have to go. I've added my findings to your answer to round it out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Bash function redirections can be overridden **dynamically** in the call to the function itself although a temporarily altered shell context can be made use of by combining Bash `aliases` and `functions` (see [Magic Aliases: A Layering Loophole in the Bourne Shell](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html)).

Non-dynamically it is the last redirection expression, i. e. the rightmost one, that overrides the previous ones if the redirection expressions refer to the same file descriptor.

```
# example
ls -ld / no_such_file 1>/dev/null 1>/dev/tty 1>&2 1>redirtest.txt
cat redirtest.txt
```

Therefore, [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17921123)'s suggestion to use `declare -f function_name` seems the way to add a final `stdout` redirection expression to override the previous ones.

```
xyzzy() { echo 'Hello, world!'; } 1>/dev/null
#func="$(declare -f xyzzy) 1>&2"
func="$(declare -f xyzzy) 1>/dev/tty"
eval "$func"
xyzzy
```